# Is it possible to use 'form_authenticity_token' inside a spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

It's possible to use `form_authencity_token` inside a controller in Rails.

```
def create
  @user = self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  @csrfToken = form_authenticity_token
  @user
end
```

My question is: is it possible to have `form_authencity_value` inside a spec? I'm testing a controller and a JSON response from `SessionsController` (**Devise**). And I have to update `csrf-token` constantly to don't get erros like: *Can't verify CSRF token authenticity* in my requests.

Please, I'm already sending to the server my `csrf-token` and it's working perfectly. My problem here is with **RSpec**, to test my **RABL** response after logging in (and logout - that is not a **RABL** view).

My test is something like this:

```
expected_response = {
  'id'          => @user.id,
  'email'       => @user.email,
  'first_name'  => @user.first_name,
  'last_name'   => @user.last_name,
  'created_at'  => @user.created_at,
  'updated_at'  => @user.updated_at,
  'csrfToken'   => # PROBLEM
}.to_json

expect(response.body).to eq(expected_response)
```

How can I have `form_authencity_value` inside my spec?

Comment: Isn't CSRF checking disabled in tests?

Comment: So, what are you saying is that it's impossible to test a controller that returns `form_authencity_token` value?

Comment: I'm not saying it is, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was. The `test` environment has a lot of things turned off and outside of integration tests not even the whole stack is loaded. If you have an action that does `render(text: form_authenticity_token)` what is the response you get in the test environment?

Comment: @tadman this is the error that I'm getting: http://d.pr/i/BXp8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to assign it to `@csrfToken`, then what you need is:

```
{
   # ...
   @csrfToken' => assigns(:csrfToken)
}
```

The `assigns` method can dig up any controller instance variable you've set.

Comment: Awesome. So simple. That turned my spec green. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: I didn't think those tokens would be generated in the test world, I've never had to verify that, but they are. So wins all around!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to stub out `form_authenticity_token` if you aren't assigning it to an instance variable.

```
    expect(controller).to receive(:form_authenticity_token).and_return('a_known_value')
```

You can use `expect` or `allow`. Now you have a known value to compare against.